# Is there a way that I can loop ifelse functions in my list of dataframes?

Tags: r

My dataframe currently looks like this:

```
employment020406 <- list(emp_02, emp_04, emp_06)
```

I want to create two new variables called `agri_work` and `TAL` in each dataset:

```
emp_02$agri_work <- ifelse(emp_02$industry == 1 | emp_02$industry == 2 | emp_02$industry == 5, 1, 0)

emp_04$agri_work <- ifelse(emp_04$industry == 1 | emp_04$industry == 2 | emp_04$industry == 5, 1, 0)

emp_06$agri_work <- ifelse(emp_06$industry == 1 | emp_06$industry == 2 | emp_06$industry == 5, 1, 0)

emp_02$tal <- ifelse(emp_02$industry == 17 | emp_02$industry == 18 | emp_02$industry == 19, 1, 0)

emp_04$tal <- ifelse(emp_04$industry == 17 | emp_04$industry == 18 | emp_04$industry == 19, 1, 0)

emp_06$tal <- ifelse(emp_06$industry == 17 | emp_06$industry == 18 | emp_06$industry == 19, 1, 0)
```

Note that `industry` exists in all 3 dataframes in the list.

Is there a way I can loop the `ifelse` function so that I can create the new variables in each dataframe without having to repeat this action many times?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can index into each element of `employment020406` using `seq_along()`. (You can also use `df$var %in% c(a, b, c)` instead of `df$var == a | df$var == b | df$var == c`.)

```
for (i in seq_along(employment020406)) {
  employment020406[[i]]$agri_work <- ifelse(employment020406[[i]]$industry %in% c(1, 2, 5), 1, 0)
  employment020406[[i]]$tal <- ifelse(employment020406[[i]]$industry %in% 17:19, 1, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to change `employment020406`, you can do this:

```
employment020406 <- lapply(employment020406, function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(tal = as.numeric(industry %in% c(17,18,19)),
           agri_work = as.numeric(industry %in% c(1,2,5))
    )
})
```

However, note that this will not change the underlying objects `emp_02`, `emp_04` and `emp_06`. If you want to change those, you could do this:

```
employment020406 <- list("emp_02", "emp_04", "emp_06") 
for(f in employment020406) {
  assign(f,get(f) %>%
           mutate(tal = as.numeric(industry %in% c(17,18,19)),
           agri_work = as.numeric(industry %in% c(1,2,5)))
  )
}
```

Comment: +1, nice note about the underlying objects and using `assign()`. You may want to include `library(dplyr)` just to make that explicit. (Or use `|>` and `base::transform()`, which also work here.)

Comment: Thanks very much for this. 
What should I do if I wanted to make a new variable called `service`  which is `ifelse(emp_04$m4ac5 > 50, 1, 0)` ?

Comment: just add it as another variable in the `mutate()` call.. Like this: `service = as.numeric(m4ac5 >50)`

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. As for `emp_04$m4ac5 > 14 & emp_04$m4ac5 < 38` would it look like `manu = as.numeric(industry > 14 & industry < 38)`

Comment: yes, that is correct. These are shortcuts, if you will, to the if_else() statements you have been writing.. Basically the `industry>14 & industry<38` will return `True` or `False` for each row; by wrapping that in `as.numeric()`, we are able to convert those into `1` and `0`, respectively